# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Login failed for user ''

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I am trying to log in with integrated security through JDBC but it can't seem to figure out my username (Login failed for user '')

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DEVSQL351;databaseName=RMSA;instanceName=investsys;integratedSecurity=true
```

And here is my bean configuration

```
<bean id="rmsaDev"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://DEVSQL351;databaseName=RMSA;instanceName=investsys;integratedSecurity=true" />
</bean>
```

I followed the instructions here, https://github.com/bhochhi/howto-guide/wiki/How-to-connect-SQL-Server-Using-Authentication-in-Spring-based-app.

Comment: Why did not you use the first solution of the instruction? Did you do the last 3 step of the instruction?

Comment: Consider trying a newer driver version than the SQL Server 2000 driver (which is ancient, probably 15+ years old), for example use the version Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver version 6.2.1. Note that these newer driver versions (since 2005) use a different class name for the driver.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll get the new driver and give that a try.